# OTA Download Limit for iOS Apps on Cellular Network

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, ota

Did Apple remove the OTA limit for downloading iOS Apps on Cellular Network?I don't see the guideline, 'Apps larger than 100MB in size will not download over cellular networks (this is automatically prohibited by the App Store)' requirement in the latest [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) Did Apple remove this by any chance? Any info will help me a lot! Cheers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1):

Apple did not remove the OTA download limit for Apps, but on September 19, 2017 they increased to limit to 150MB, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09192017b).

iTunesConnect will warn you if your App is exceeding the current OTA cellular download limit.

More information on how to measure the OTA App size, as well is information on how to reduce the size can be found here: [Apple Technical Q&A QA1795](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html)